# Extract pixels from TextureSurface using glReadPixels resulting in bad image Bitmap

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to send bitmap images every few seconds from the SurfaceTexture view in Android. I read the pixels using `glReadPixels()` and the image I get is something like

[image: This].

My code looks something like this:

```
int size = this.width * this.height;
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size * 4);
bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
gl.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL10.GL_RGB, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb);
int pixelsBuffer[] = new int[size];
bb.asIntBuffer().get(pixelsBuffer);
bb = null;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    pixelsBuffer[i] = ((pixelsBuffer[i] & 0xff00ff00)) | ((pixelsBuffer[i] & 0x000000ff) << 16) | ((pixelsBuffer[i] & 0x00ff0000) >> 16);
}
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
bm.setPixels(pixelsBuffer, size - width, -width, 0, 0, width, height);
if(now - init > 5000) {
      init = now;
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
      byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
      String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

note: now and init is just a long with `currentTimeMillis()` function.

Does anyone knows what's wrong? Or is there any better way to convert the image to base64 String because I need to send this to a server.

Answer (score 0):

The thing of which I can be confident:

```
gl.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL10.GL_RGB, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb);
```

Probably wants to be:

```
gl.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb);
```

... otherwise each pixel is being returned as three bytes, and then probably being spaced in a manner you don't want unless you've also adjusted `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT`. Your code otherwise seems to assume four bytes.

(EDIT: this is one of the "Common Mistakes: Texture upload and pixel reads" per [the OpenGL.org wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Texture_upload_and_pixel_reads))

I'm such a Java/Android dunce that I'm taking it as given that you're confident in creating a bitmap with a 16-bit `Bitmap.Config.RGB_565` format but then posting 32-bit data via `setPixels`. It seems a bit weird though — especially given the depth of JPEG wouldn't `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888` be more appropriate?

Comment: I tried to use `GL10.GL_RGBA` but the performance is not favorable. How can I use the `GL10.GL_RGB` and setting the pixels with `Bitmap.Config.RGB_565` bitmap format configuration?